# Trouble Creating Cross Project Reference for Xcode 4

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, static-libraries

I'm trying to pick up some better code organization practices. Over time, I've developed a collection of utility-type files that I import into all of my iOS projects. Rather than continuing to copy them in, I want to setup a separate "Library" project which builds these files to a static library. Then, I reference the static library in my app's project.

In Xcode 4.2 I created a new project "JTLibrary" with a static library as the target, added some files, and it builds as expected.

Now, I created a new project "LibraryTest" which should behave like any other app project I might be working on. My understanding was that I should be able to drag the JTLibrary project into this project to create a cross project reference. Once that was done, I would link LibraryTest's binary against the static library from JTLibrary.

However, when I drag the JTLibary project into the LibraryTest project, it does not appear expandable. I expected I should be able to see the files in it, etc. See screenshot below:

[image]

Can anyone offer some insight to why the project appears like this rather than expandable? Once it is expandable, I should be able to see the static library in the app's project.

Thanks!

**EDIT 11/7**

It's worth mentioning that I'm working with a VERY basic project now. From the new project window, select Framework & Library >> Cocoa Touch Static Library. Add one function to the default class and build.

I can copy the header and .a files into another project and use them successfully, but if I try to drag the project itself, it appears like the picture above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To create a subproject simply drag a project node from Finder into Xcode.

DO NOT open two Xcode instances and drag the project node from one to the other (that's why the subproject is not expandable).

Comment: Thanks! I had tried closing the static library project, but not closing out of both projects. Restarting Xcode and only opening only the app project allowed me to create the reference correctly. Thanks!